# Woocommerce Multilingual issue, How to add and edit string.

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, multilingual

I am working on an multilingual e-Shop using Woocommerce. I downloaded the woocommerce .po and .mo, they work fine.

However, I added some custom content into some .php files. 
And there are some string that I want to translate.

E.g. I found the code in "templates/content-product.php" and the code is at line 64:

I get into the .po file.
And added:

#: templates/content-product.php:64
msgid "View Product"
msgstr "查看產品"

But it doesn't work.
How to check the exact line of code to make it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should copy template files into your theme's WooCommerce folder. And then if you modify strings, use the `gettext()` functions with a custom text domain.

For example:

```
_e( 'Some sample text', 'my-text-domain' );
```

Then you will be able to generate mo/po files for the 'my-text-domain'.

[Developer's Handbook on internationalizing plugins](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/)
[Codex: i18n for WordPress Developers](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers)