# How to add new word to localization files in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, localization, woocommerce

I am extending Woocommerce plugin for Wordpress currently. I added a new label with a text field. Currently the label text is hardcoded. I need to know, how can I add the label word to the localisation files so it will change depending on the selected language.

Comment: try this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/codestyling-localization/

Comment: I tried it, but I could not see a option to add a new string. I can just see the edit option. Am I wrong?

Comment: You must use `gettext()` functions and probably a new text domain. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/28267832/383847